# How to secure my flutter application and its user login credentials

Tags: dart

Iam developing a application in flutter , our testing team reported my app not secure becouse they cought username and password when they take fridadump , please help me to fix it . how i make secure authentication in flutter ,

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is about leaving the password in plain text, you can encrypt it with the `encrypt` package and decrypt it when you need it. Passwords will be visible a very short time (will be selected on the next garbage collection cycle) or you can overwrite the value of the variable that holds password to erase it from memory

[encrypt package on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)